# Difference between program counter and location counter

Tags: computer-science

I keep reading in my computer organization book that the PC (program counter) holds the address of the current instruction. But my professor keeps saying it holds the address of the next instruction. Which is correct?

Competing definitions:

http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch05s02.html

and

https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/program-counter

Comment: I think "Current" Instruction and "Next" Instruction is same.

Comment: @engineerk: That makes absolutely no sense. *Next* is what comes **after** current, so they can't possibly be the same if the code is doing anything at all. Even stuck in an endless loop, there's always a next instruction, which is clearly not the same as the current instruction.

Comment: Sorry, I answered more precisely. It may help your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer to difference between program counter and location counter

Location counter is used to point available memory.
Program counter is a special location counter for memory to store instruction.

## Answer to which is correct

Both is correct.

Program Counter points to the next instruction.
While Instruction is being executed, Program counter points to current instruction.
When instructions is done, program counter is incremented, and program counter points to the next instruction to be executed.